React record video and save in s3 multipart upload
I am trying to make simple application of recording video and saving it simultaneously,
My approach is to record video and upload it s3 bucket , one after another in multipart
here initialy on click the recording starts and uploads also works fine , but when stop recording is clicked , it creates and issue , and video is not saved in s3
import React, { useRef, useCallback, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

  
  export const RecordNSave = () => {
    const [bytesRecorded, setBytesRecorded] = useState(0);
    const [bytesUploaded, setBytesUploaded] = useState(0);
    const [location, setLocation] = useState('');
    const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
    
    const videoRef = useRef(null);
    const mediaRecorderRef = useRef(null);
    const streamRef = useRef(null);
    const chunksRef = useRef([]);
    
    const BUCKET_NAME = S3_BUCKET;
  
    useEffect(() => {
      AWS.config.update({
        credentials: {
    accessKeyId: '',
    secretAccessKey: '',
        region: 'eu-north-1'
        }
      });
  
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: { width: 1280, height: 720 }
      })
      .then(stream => {
        console.log("Successfully received user media.");
        if (videoRef.current) {
          videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
        }
        streamRef.current = stream;
      })
      .catch(error => console.error("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error));
  
      return () => {
        if (streamRef.current) {
          streamRef.current.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        }
      };
    }, []);
  
    const startRecording = async () => {
      const s3 = new AWS.S3();
      setIsRecording(true);
      chunksRef.current = [];
  
      let options = { mimeType: "video/webm;codecs=vp9" };
      if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
        options = { mimeType: "video/webm;codecs=vp8" };
        if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
          options = { mimeType: "video/webm" };
          if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
            options = { mimeType: "" };
          }
        }
      }
  
      try {
        mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(streamRef.current, options);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Exception while creating MediaRecorder: " + e);
        return;
      }
  
      const s3Key = `video-file-${new Date().toISOString()}.webm`;
      const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: s3Key
      };
  
      let uploadId;
  
      try {
        const { UploadId } = await s3.createMultipartUpload(params).promise();
        uploadId = UploadId;
  
        mediaRecorderRef.current.ondataavailable = async (event) => {
          if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
            chunksRef.current.push(event.data);
            setBytesRecorded(prev => prev + event.data.size);
  
            try {
              const partNumber = chunksRef.current.length;
              const { ETag } = await s3.uploadPart({
                Body: event.data,
                Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
                Key: s3Key,
                PartNumber: partNumber,
                UploadId: uploadId,
                ContentLength: event.data.size
              }).promise();
  
              setBytesUploaded(prev => prev + event.data.size);
              return { ETag, PartNumber: partNumber };
            } catch (err) {
              console.error("Error uploading part:", err);
            }
          }
        };
  
        mediaRecorderRef.current.onstop = async () => {
          try {
            const result = await s3.completeMultipartUpload({
              Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
              Key: s3Key,
              UploadId: uploadId,
              MultipartUpload: {
                Parts: chunksRef.current.map((_, index) => ({
                  ETag: `"etag${index + 1}"`,
                  PartNumber: index + 1
                }))
              }
            }).promise();
            
            setLocation(result.Location);
            console.log("Uploaded successfully.");
          } catch (err) {
            console.error("Error completing multipart upload:", err);
            await s3.abortMultipartUpload({
              Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
              UploadId: uploadId,
              Key: s3Key
            }).promise();
            console.log("Multipart upload aborted");
          }
        };
  
        mediaRecorderRef.current.start(15000);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error starting recording:", err);
      }
    };
  
    const stopRecording = () => {
      if (mediaRecorderRef.current) {
        mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
        setIsRecording(false);
      }
    };
  
    return (
      <div>
        <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay muted playsInline />
        <button onClick={startRecording} disabled={isRecording}>Start Recording</button>
        <button onClick={stopRecording} disabled={!isRecording}>Stop Recording</button>
        <div>Bytes Recorded: <span>{bytesRecorded}</span></div>
        <div>Bytes Uploaded: <span>{bytesUploaded}</span></div>
        <div>Location: <span>{location}</span></div>
      </div>
    );
  };



first error msg
<Error><Code>InvalidPart</Code><Message>One or more of the specified parts could not be found.  The part may not have been uploaded, or the specified entity tag may not match the part's entity tag.</Message><UploadId>5fFV7BhBtNJTxJ2_8OoOCjVz7rA1xIolAbPdqywJtkqrAQiKmIfxoXRcETAnLxO9No.ehsSj9YgglwxRnU.FO89FjjMeEM989WTfG99h9T4fOSQprR4pEHmscs8nu0T1</UploadId><PartNumber>1</PartNumber><ETag>etag1</ETag><RequestId>0FP6RGE8EWX5XP98</RequestId><HostId>YGBO/5RfGU6xWarsxSHWrlfjdGLP8jogx7vTm7sXtONH+Wo4s8NN4sWVYrkTk2oS6UU2awtQIw8=</HostId></Error>

and other 200 ok msg
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"><Name>webcamrec</Name><Prefix></Prefix><Marker></Marker><MaxKeys>0</MaxKeys><IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated></ListBucketResult>

can anyone help me in fixing the issue

<ETag>etag1</ETag> that is not a valid ETag.  You need to use the ETags returned from S3 for each part of the upload.
